# FastAPI. Websocket with database: service freezes

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I have a project on fastapi to implement a chat between users with a record of messages in the database. I use fastapi.WebSocket and sqlalchemy to work with the database.

I came across a problem: when there are 50+ connections to a websocket from a user or users, and there is an active distribution of messages, the whole service freezes, does not allow creating new connections via a websocket, no functions respond, and this remains even if you stop sending messages and that's it users will be disconnected from weightboxes.

If I remove the functionality of writing to the database, then everything works well, without freezes

Tell me, please, what could be the problem?

I tried using database.close() after db using, but that didn't help

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing some of your code.

Comment: Look at the number of active connections to the database - if you have max simultaneous connections set to 50, and all those 50 are available, you might not handle that properly and keep waiting for something to be available / retry it forever. But, without code that reproduces the issue, it's impossible for someone to say something specific.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.